# table2CSV and picnet.table.filter showing weird character in CSV export

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a working HTML table to CSV working using the plugins below.

```
http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php
```

I am also using jquery tablesorter and table filter

```
jquery.tablesorter.js
picnet.table.filter.min.js
```

My problem right now is when I export the CSV with picnet.table.filter enabled, the CSV has some weird characters on top below headers. Looks like this is came from the filter input box.

```
", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, "
```

If I disable the picnet.table.filter, the CSV is okay and it shows the headers and data.

sample data is:

```
"Name","Address","Email","Comment"
", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, "
"John Smith","USA","john@john.net","No Comment"
```

Anyone got an idea how to eliminate the second line with characters as I don't want to give up the filters.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the tableCSV.js file. Looks like it can be handle in this file but I am not good in javascript. http://pastebin.com/xfMBNkMa